# How to decompose a relation with a given set of FDs

Tags: database, database-design

My given relation R={A, B, C, D, E} FDs F={AB->C, DE->C, B->C}
I have come up with R1=ABCDE and R2=ABE, but I feel like I am missing something
My final assumption:
R1=ABC, R2=BD, R3=ABE

Comment: Given a relation schema with a set of FDs, many decompositions are possible, generally to obtain some normal form or to satisfy some particular property. So, which kind of decomposition are you trying to obtain? As it is now, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I need the decompositon to be BCNF

Comment: Decompositions for BCNF are done by following some algorithm (for instance the classical decomposition algorithm). Are you following some algorithm? (For instance, to find which dependencies violates the normal form, etc.)

Comment: Sorry I had to refresh. The intersections of the decomposed relations have to be  FDs